# Insertar elementos CSS al enviar un correo mediante laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-5

Hola buen dia compañeros, mi duda es que como puedo mandar estilos `CSS` mediante correo electronico, tengo mis imagenes y los estilos CSS en un servidor pero al momento de enviarlos, solo aparecen las imagenes y no los estilos, alguna manera de hacer esto?
Este es el cuerpo del mensaje que envio

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Hello México</title>
            <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.hellomexico.mx/assets/img/fabicon.png" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hellomexico.mx/assets/css/style.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://miservidor/assets/css/resset.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://miservidor/assets/css/bootstrap.css">


        <meta name="description" content="Hello México Agencia de Contenidos Digitales">
        <meta name="keywords" content="HelloMéxico,HelloMx,Hello,México,Agencia,Contenidos,Digitales,HelloWord,App,Mobile,Aplicaciones,Móviles,Desarrollo,Software,Android,Java,
         iOS,Swift,C#,.NET,Unity,UNITY,Angular,AngularJS,JS,JSON,Ajax,Javascript,HTML5,CSS3,PHP,MySQL,SQL,Oculus,VR,OculusVr,OculusRift,Rift,Leap,Motion,LeapMotion,Digital,Experience,
         DigitalExperience,Experiencias,Digitales,Activaciones,Instagram,Facebook,Twitter,Landing,Page,LandingPage,Aplicaciones,Web,Sitios,Google,Server,Desarrolladores,Servicios,Services
         Consumo,Push,Notificaction,Interfaces,Gráfica,Interfaz,Mockups,Wireframes,Servicio,Social,Becarios,Practicas,Profesionales,Ultra,Plus,sdasdasd">
        <meta name="author" content="Hello México">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>

    <body style="font-family: 'glight', sans-serif;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse fixed-top-inverse">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Navega</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-yellow">
                         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://www.hellomexico.mx/assets/img/images/logo_menu.png" width="50px"></a>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><h4>¿Cómo tener un <strong>Office Garden</strong>?</h4></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <br><br><br>
        <div>
            <img id="ninoHello" src="http://miservidor/assets/img/INFOGRAFIA_OFFICE_GARDEN_V01.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="foooter" align="center">
            <p id="txtLight3">Para ver el artículo completo, da click <a href="#">aquí</a>.</p>
            <p id="txtLight3">Si ya no quieres recibir nuestros mensajes o deseas cancelar tu suscripción de nuesta lista de correos, da click <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/rechazar/{{$correos->id_cor}}">aquí</a>.</p>
            <!--<p id="txtLight3">Tel: 55 7095 6397</p>-->
        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

    <footer>
    </footer>
</html>
```

y Esto es en mi controlador

```
 public function mandarCorreos()
{
    $aceptados = DB::table('correos_automaticos')
    ->where('rechazar', '=', 0)
    ->get();

    foreach ($aceptados as $a) {
        $correos = CorreosAutomaticos::findOrFail($a->id_cor);
         Mail::to($a->correo)->send(new MandarCorreosMail($correos));
    }

    $aceptados = DB::table('correos_automaticos')
    ->where('rechazar', '=', 0)
    ->get();

    $rechazados = DB::table('correos_automaticos')
    ->where('rechazar', '=', 1)
    ->get();

    return view('Correos.correos', ['aceptados'=>$aceptados, 'rechazados'=>$rechazados]);
}
```

Les agradesco su ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno lo que yo hago es poner todo el contenido CSS en el mismo archivo. En tu caso tienes que poner todo el contenido de:

```
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://www.hellomexico.mx/assets/img/fabicon.png" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.hellomexico.mx/assets/css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://miservidor/assets/css/resset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://miservidor/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

lo que tiene que hace es colocar los estilos css dentro de los contenido html como es la siguiente forma, usted puede colocar los enlaces externos, pero el sistema de email de servidor  lo que hacer es eliminar eso enlaces o bloquearlos por cuestión de seguridad , eso pasa igual con las imágenes,svg, si utilizar google como el sistema stmp no le va a enviar las imágenes, tiene que buscar una forma de enviar la imágenes como archivo adjunto

```
 <button style="
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007bff;
    border-color: #007bff;
   display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;


    " type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary">Get started</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No muchos clientes de email soportan las stylesheet externa. Lo que te recomiendo es que coloques los estilos dentro de la etiqueta **style**

Answer (score 1):

Para dar estilo a tus correos es necesario incluir los estilos en cada una de las etiquetas, bastante pesado y tedioso si quieres darle un formato Bootstrap.

Para esto es necesario agregar un paquete que procesará las clases de estilos que agregues normalmente usando Bootstrap y las agregará como estilo en cada etiqueta, logrando enviar correos con estilos idénticos a los de tu aplicación.

Para instalar el paquete sigue los pasos de este post: [Agregar Bootstrap o CSS a los correos electrónicos en Laravel](https://forcsec.com/blog/agregar-bootstrap-css-a-los-correos-electronicos-en-laravel).